# SQL Server find stored procedures that return result sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, information-schema

In SQL Server, it is possible to declare stored procedures that return one or several result sets:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.proc1
AS 
SELECT 1 a, 2 b UNION SELECT 3 a, 4 b;
```

I'm looking into trying to detect all such stored procedures from the dictionary views in SQL Server 2008+. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to be able to find a distinctive flag identifying such a procedure in either:

- `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`
- `sys.procedures`

Here's also a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/18e71/1), showing that there appears to be no difference in meta data between procedures returning result sets, and those not returning result sets.

Can it be done in a formally correct way (not looking for any hacks / tricks)? If so, how?

Comment: One possible solution is to execute all the stored procedures, output the results into other language, like `ruby`, and count the result sets there.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but that's not really a very good solution, given that I don't even know what side-effects I'm going to trigger by executing those procedures.

Comment: I agree that's not a good solution. For some stored procedures, you also need to know the parameters there. Another possible way is to parse the stored procedures, but parsing the stored procedure codes is not easy...

Comment: @zhongxiao37: Thanks, but I'm really looking for *formally correct* solutions :-)

Comment: It isn't possible 100%. An `EXEC(@SomeString)` command could either return a result set or not - dependant on the contents of the string. The designers in Visual Studio etc typically use `SET fmtonly ON` AFAIK. SQL Server 2012 does have some new metadata functions in this area.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Good point: There can be result sets or not depending on the actual parameters. You could put this as an answer. Also, the SQL Server 2012 metadata functions would be very interesting to learn about, even if this questions is originally about SQL Server 2008+

Comment: What you are asking for is not tracked in sql server. What is the end goal here?

Comment: @SeanLange: The end goal is source code generation for [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org). In Oracle, for instance, a procedure returning a `ref_cursor` can be clearly identified. But as Martin Smith mentioned, the way SQL Server allows for returning cursors, this may not be formally trackable before such procedures are actually executed...

Comment: I think you are right. Of course sql server doesn't return cursors. Cursors in sql server are a 4 letter word. :D

Comment: I don't think it is possible; a stored procedure can contain dynamic SQL that constructs queries (or calls to other stored procedures) and return an arbitrary number of results (counts and cursors). This means that at compile time (create or alter) it is not possible to determine if (and how many) result sets are produced.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Thanks for joining. I think that is essentially what Martin Smith had said as well, and I think you guys are right. If you phrase that as an answer, I'll accept...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible. In SQL Server a stored procedure can contain dynamic SQL that constructs queries (or calls to other stored procedures that - for example - return result sets). This isn't just limited to dynamic SQL though, for example having a `SELECT` in an `IF` will also decide whether a stored procedure returns 0 or 1 result sets. Any produced result set that isn't handled by the stored procedure itself is returned to the user.

So it is possible for a stored procedure to return an arbitrary number of results (counts and result sets). This means that at compile time (create or alter) it is not possible to determine if (and how many) result sets are actually produced, which is probably why you can't find this in the metadata.

Comment: That makes sense. I've often thought that this feature of some databases corresponds to what Oracle calls a `ref_cursor`, but that's not the case. Oracle `ref_cursor` types are defined in advance. It's well-known whether a cursor will be returned from a procedure - unlike in this case, where you indeed simply cannot know.

Comment: @LukasEder I think this is possible because of TDS, I haven't looked at the entire spec, but I believe it streams `(table descriptor, (rows)*)*` until it signals an end, which means it is very flexible in what it can return.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) actually supports fetching of multiple result sets via [`ResultQuery.fetchMany()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/ResultQuery.html#fetchMany--), which is just a short-cut for the relevant JDBC code that runs `Statement.getMoreResults()` and `Statement.getResultSet()` in a tedious loop. I just hadn't made the connection of this behaviour and the fact that stored procedures can indeed return any number of results in T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the stored procedures that contain a select statement with

```
select distinct 
    o.name,
    o.type_desc
from syscomments c
inner join sys.objects o on
    c.id = o.object_id
where
    [text] like '%select%' and
    type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
```

But the syscomments tables include all the procedure text, comments included.

Comment: That's very vague. I mean, the `SELECT` could really be part of an `INSERT .. SELECT`, or an update of a view, such as `UPDATE (SELECT ..) SET ..`, so this doesn't really tell me anything about potential matches...